# Why does the Execution Policy Change prompt pop up 50% of the time?

Tags: windows, powershell

```
Execution Policy Change
The execution policy helps protect you from scripts that you do not trust. Changing the execution policy might expose
you to the security risks described in the about_Execution_Policies help topic at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. Do you want to change the execution policy?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "N"):
```

The prompt above pops up maybe about half the time I run a ps1 script.
Sometimes I can just close the Powershell window, run the script again, and it will go through without issues.
Other times I get the prompt again.

This has always happened in various builds and versions of Windows 10 (Insider, LTSC, Home), including fresh installs, and is now happening in 11.

I made sure to run `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` before running any scripts.

Is this just yet another bug from Microsoft?

Comment: The execution policy can be configured by a group policy. Can you be more specific about what the script does and wether it imports modules?

Comment: The script doesn't import modules, but it auto-elevates to admin and installs a single module (powershell-yaml). It also uninstalls selected packages, installs and configures selected packages, restores a few files from a backup, imports group policies and reg files, edits user path and creates new Send-to context menu entries. But the prompt pops up with other, simpler, scripts as well.

Comment: You need to run get-executionpolicy on the systems that are and are not showing the prompt to see what the policy is on these systems. There's a good chance this will tell you what you need to know.

Comment: Running `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List` on the most recent system I ran into this on returns `RemoteSigned` for `CurrentUser` and `Undefined` for everything else.